# Fluent API vs FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluent, fluentvalidation

there is this Fluent API which is preferred over Data Annotation in the model to be used for validation. Then we also have FluentValidation. If we have fluent API, we still need FluentValidation? Or Fluent API is only for model while FluentValidation is for everything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fluentValidation is for validation rules framework. While simple validation rule can be ex: text length is 100 characters or it is a required field, in most business cases the rules are much more complex and it enables to define them in a easy to read/write manner.

Fluent API is Entity Framework extension that enables a easy to read/write to use Entity framework, that is used to map a data source like a database to C# data transfer object classes. DTO's do not have business logic in them they are translated to models that do have them.

Partly the question is where do you put the validation? Lets say your application is layered to - client side, server side, microservices, database. Should it be in one of them or all of them or something in between and the short answer is - yes.

You should have database rules, that prevent invalid states to be stored. At the same time database calls are costly and time consuming. Adding all business rules to database and its constraints, setting up triggers, etc is called database first architecture. While that is possible, usually it is possible to set up a cache that will be hit 80-98% of time instead. The general problem with client side validation is that it can be bypassed, and multiple other reasons.

In short - there are limitations on every validation solution or how you abstract your application. Devs's usually try to write clean code with minimal effort and often they are required to add tests and often they do not write schema or database integration test, so they add business logic to models and write tests for it.

Additionally, Fluent validation is for model validation and Fluent api is for data source access.

Comment: "Additionally, Fluent validation is for model validation". If I have viewmodel, so my fluentValidation should be on viewmodel right?

Comment: You can, but that does not mean you should. Generally it should be inside the Model. This makes the logic more loosely coupled from the UI, so if a new UI or a view comes a long you can reuse the model.

Comment: If I put my validation in Model, does it violates the domain-driven design whereby the core class *depends* on something like Entity Framework Fluent API?

Comment: @Steve it depends on how you layer your application, but yes, generally you do not want a Entity framework in your core models project/lib. EF returns DTO's and they should not contain ANY LOGIC. Typically an automapper is used to create models of them and they have business logic, etc in them and this is generally where you would keep validation rules - inside models.

Comment: A "fluent API" isn't necessarily tied to Entity Framework. Is the OP asking about fluent APIs in general?